# OS_BOOT_FAILURE error caused a rest on my machine! Was wondering how to recover my original github repository

Tags: git

The OS_BOOT_FAILURE on my Window 10 machine caused a complete reset resulting in the removing of a lot of data. When I tried to re-setup V.S. Code, Git Bash, and my Github repo, I wasn't able to access my original repo the way it originally was before losing my data. Is there a way to fully recover your original repo to its original connected state? I don't want to clone my repo. I'm hoping there is a way to fully recover my repo to its original connected state.

Comment: Can you define "original connected state" I'm not sure to fully understand ? If everything was pushed to the remote repo (understand the repo on github), you just have to `git clone` it, you'll be able to use it a before

Comment: @Ant0ine64 : Here's a better way to explain it. All files and folders stored inside the file explorer section of V.S. Code gets pushed to Github to create a new repo on the master branch using Git Bash. You create an init, user.name, user.password, remote add origin, push -u origin master etc... this process gives you admin privileges that cloning a repo does not have. After the OS_BOOT_FAILURE all my data was wiped; meaning all the code that was stored inside my V.S. Code file explorer is gone and that original connection to my repo is lost. Cloning just creates a copy, I dont want a copy

Comment: @mr-daniels "this process gives you admin privileges that cloning a repo does not have" this is not true, there is no such thing as admin priviliege on a repo. You just need to clone it (maybe reset correctly user.* config) and you'll have the same repos, with the same abilities. If you tried it, what makes you think you don't have "admin privileges" ? If it's not how you want it, how you would like it to be ?

Comment: @Ant0ine64 : YES!!! it is TRUE!!! The REPO!!! You create can not be accessed by outside users... Unless you grant users privileges with limited access! (i.e. the team you're working with) I can clone any publicly accessible repo, however, it does not give me admin privileges if I do own that repo... I can not go into any repo and create personal access tokens... what part of that do you not understand? Furthermore, when I lost all my data... I was not able to establish I was the original owner of my repo via gitbash. after reading the docs I was not able to find a solution, so now I'm here

Comment: @mr-daniels I think you are referring to a repo hosted on github, those privileges aren't proper to git but specific to you remote (github in this case). You need to consider searching this for github. I think this page could help you https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/troubleshooting-cloning-errors